# HtmlHelper not loaded in tutorial example

Tags: cakephp

I followed the tutorial to create a blog for CakePHP 1.3 up to [this step](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1536/Creating-Post-Views) but keep getting error when running the app:

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: View::$Html [APP\views\posts\index.ctp, line 27]
```

Line 27:

```
echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'], array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id']));
```

Apparently CakePHP doesn't load the HtmlHelper class, I check over and over again in my controller, the Html should be loaded properly.

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
  var $name = 'Posts';
  var $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

  function index() {
    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
  }
}
```

When I added this line to the view (index.ctp), it works

```
$this->Html = &$this->loaded['html'];
```

But apparently I can't do that for every ctp file. I'm running Windows 7, WAMP 2, PHP 5.3.5, CakePHP 1.3.7 stable.

Anyone has a clue?

Comment: Is the FormHelper being loaded in your views? What do you get if you do pr($this->Html) in your view? How about pr($html)? Until CakePHP 1.3, helpers were accessed directly instead of through the View object. In CakePHP 1.3 both methods should work. Does the plain $html->link() or $form->input() methods work for you?

Comment: @mtnorthrop Thanks. It worked beautifully! I'll inform CakePHP team about this

Comment: Huy, I'm glad this helped. Is it possible that you don't actually have CakePHP 1.3 installed and downloaded 1.2 instead? You should be able to find out if you check cake/VERSION.txt.

Comment: Hey. I did use 1.3. I posted on the CakePHP mailing list and someone pointed out that downloading 1.2 and replace the `cake` folder would solve the problem. Guess it's 1.3 bug then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment by mtnorthrop above:

> Is the FormHelper being loaded in your
>   views? What do you get if you do
>   pr($this->Html) in your view? How
>   about pr($html)? Until CakePHP 1.3,
>   helpers were accessed directly instead
>   of through the View object. In CakePHP
>   1.3 both methods should work. Does the plain $html->link() or $form->input()
>   methods work for you? – mtnorthrop 51
>   mins ago

Answer (score 0):

From the book:

> "The HtmlHelper is available in all
>   views by default. If you're getting an
>   error informing you that it isn't
>   there, it's usually due to its name
>   being missing from a manually
>   configured $helpers controller
>   variable."

You shouldn't need to specify it in your controllers. Perhaps somehow doing so is interfering with the core? BTW, you don't need to specify Form either.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried removing that `var $helpers=...` line but it still gives the same error